# IE SCRIPT5008: Invalid Left-hand Side in asignment

Tags: javascript

To be fair i copy and pasted this to shuffle an array and works everywhere except in IE i get this error: SCRIPT5008: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (116,5). Points to this line `[a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];`

```js
function shuffle(a) 
{
  for (let i = a.length; i; i--) 
  {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `let` to `var`.. Unless your pre-compiling this some browsers might not yet have the `let`..   `let` isn't doing anything special here anyway..

Comment: I changed `let` to`var` but it still fails on this line `[a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];`

Comment: Oh, never noticed that part.. It's special array features, I think it's array expansion or something like that, so you will need to either pre-compile with say babel..   I'll post the version babel give as an answer.

Comment: edit.. I think it's called  "Destructuring assignment" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is using some enhanced ES-Next features, some browsers may not yet have all functions of ES-Next implemented..

One option if you get code like this, you can use babel to compile it.
For such a small function, you could even use babel.io website to see what it compiles to, so for example here is this function compiled via babel..

```
function shuffle(a) {
  for (var i = a.length; i; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    var _ref = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    a[i - 1] = _ref[0];
    a[j] = _ref[1];
  }
}
```